Linear gradient with css variable - Error
I am trying to create a linear gradient using css variables but getting an error. This is example code:
:root {
    --Red:red;
    --Blue:blue;
}
#pageSubHeaderBackground {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--Red) 0%, var(--Blue) 100%);
}

In Visual Studio, I am getting squiggly line under 0% and it says "Expected ,." and the gradient is not showing up properly in the website.

your code you shared is fine

@TemaniAfif, could this have something to do with my root being in another file. I am using @import url("css/base.css"); to import the css.

I found the answer. It seems base.css was loading after the main css file. I have added link element to load it before the main css file. This solves it.
